# Document Library Versions.aspx in Sharepoint

Tags: asp.net, sharepoint, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-api

1.I have a user that wants to view the current items version history on the dispform.aspx(Item Details)
2.The version history must display all metadata for each version. Library has 5 columns and I need to display the data in those columns everytime the version changes.

I have been trying to get the version information using SharePoint Designer and cannot find out where the versions page is stored. What is the best way to meet this requirement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The versions.aspx file exists within the 12 hive
C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\web server extensions\12\TEMPLATE\LAYOUTS

This can give you information on how you might go about using the object model to create your own page that will give this information.

This is a non-trivial task and will require programming level knowledge of SharePoint.